# Binding Button to Boolean in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, awesomium, mahapps.metro

I have a problem with a seemingly simple WPF application. I'm using [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/)'s `MetroWindow` as my main Window which allows me to place buttons on the top of the window. Following their Getting Started example i have placed a few buttons on the top of the window. One of these buttons is a refresh button that allows a user to refresh the content of another control (Awesomium `WebControl`). What i would like to do is somehow bind the Refresh button to the `WebControl`'s `IsNavigating` property (which is a boolean) so that the image on the button changes when the browser is navigating.

Here is the XAML i'm using for the button:

```
<Button x:Name="C_BTN_Refresh" Click="C_BTN_Refresh_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_refresh}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
         </Rectangle>
     </StackPanel>
 </Button>
```

Keep in mind i'm very new to WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a converter like this:

```
public class BoolVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then include the converter as a resource in your view like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:BoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use like this on your button:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsNavigating, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to change the image of the button instead of setting visibility? The image is set here: `<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_refresh}" />`

Comment: And I would add that you can also do the reverse if you wanted to conditionally HIDE or COLLAPSE by creating a BoolToHidden or BoolToCollapsed.  This way different fields could be bound to the same logical field and respectively show/hide/collapse a control instead of creating multiple flags.  It works great for a project I have going on.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a simple converter to do that. Do a quick search for BooleanToVisibility converter and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using converter is a way to go. But, I refer to using trigger binding to IsNavigating in viewmodel.

```
   <Button x:Name="C_BTN_Refresh" Click="C_BTN_Refresh_Click">
       <Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNavigating}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QuickDrawBarPinned}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel> 
    </Button>
```

Hope this help.